# Select value from HTML dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, automation

My goal is to choose/insert a value from cell "X"(i) to the dropdown element on the web.

With my current code, I mange to insert the value to the "search" bar of the dropdown element > click the drop down icon which opens the drop down list > 
See the value with childrent related to the value

the problem is that the change isn't happening after  saving since i can't find a way to mimic left click on the "found" value inside the dropdown list.
If it helps, there are 2 ways for a user to apply changes when choosing a value on that elemnt:

> 1. insert the value in the elemtns search bar > click the dropdown icon
>      choose the value once it appears (takes few seconds to load up)
> 2. click the drop down icon > click on a open "children" value icon >
>      choose with left click the desired value.
>
> Note: Pressing "enter" won't work. it will "focus" the elemnt but if I
>   will try to save it no changes will be applied.

My VBA code [trying to change the value from APAC to EMEA]:

```
 Sub User_Setup()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'----------------------------------here I define elemnts for the loop
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fields")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim values() As String
Dim b As Long
Dim frm As Object
Dim dt As Object
'---------------------------------------------here I define Internet Explorer
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'--------------------------------------------- here I define range for the loop
For i = 2 To LastRow
' ---------------------------------------------here I ask the Internet explorer to be visable & Navigate to value in cell "H"i
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate sht.Range("A" & i).Value

' ---------------------------------------------here I ask the Internet explorer to wait few seconds
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Set Doc = IE.document
'--------------------------------- Here is my issue with the dropdown
Doc.getElementById("tab7").Click ' clicks the tab where the dropdown exists
Doc.getElementById("ResourceWorkgroup").Value = sht.Range("X" & i).Value ' This is the value needs be choosen in the dropdown
Doc.getElementById("ResourceWorkgroup").FireEvent "onfocus" ' this event should make the value just inserted be highlited
'---- 
Doc.getElementById("_IB_imgResourceWorkgroup").Click ' this is the action that mimic mouse click on the "open drop down" icon
  Doc.getElementById("_IB_imgResourceWorkgroup").FireEvent "onfocus" 'not sure if this line is  even helpful
'----
'NOTE:I manage to enter the value in the search field, and the click the dropdown list icon,
'(mimic the mouse click on the open dropdown list icon) without really choosing the value.

 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
 Doc.getElementById("Master_IdBtnSave").Click ' click on save button
 Doc.getElementById("Master_IdBtnSave").FireEvent "*******" 'trigger the event of saving (not sure if this neccery aswell)

Next i

End Sub
```

Below is the html code from the web:

```html
<div id="Master_cphBody_divWorkgroup">
                <label class="txt" id="Master_cphBody_lblWorkgroup" for="Master_cphBody_ResourceWorkgroup"><span></span>Workgroup:</label>
                
<script src="/JS/InputBoxWithWkgResCusConDropdownTree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../JS/inJsValidate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
       
<table class="offsetLeft" style="margin: 2px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-image: none; padding-left: 1px; vertical-align: middle; white-space: nowrap;">
            <input name="ResourceWorkgroup" title="APAC" id="ResourceWorkgroup" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none; width: 380px;" onkeyup="_IBDD_InputKeyDown(this, null, event)" onfocus="this.focus();this.select();" type="text" value="APAC" controltype="TWDropDown" showclientportalparticipant="" entity="" ctype="IB" searchtt="Press ENTER or click the drop-down list and select a value." dirty="0" requiresla="0" requesttype="" additionalid="" allresources="false" allrequests="false" selectedbydblclick="0" multiselid="" multiselect="0" adjusty="0" adjustx="0" disablesearchcriteria="0" includesystem="false" ignoreaccesscheck="False" portfoliofilter="" surveyfilter="" requestfilter="" productfilter="" invoicefilter="" competitorfilter="" campaignfilter="" reportfilter="" oppfilter="" taskfilter="" prjfilter="" engfilter="" cusfilter="" wgpfilter="-2032307166" cfilter="" rfilter="" inputlength="50" smodel="3" referenceposition="" ddstyle="" ddheight="350" ddwidth="400" cptype="res" cpvalue="APAC" cpid="6c9ef9d1-daef-11d2-882b-006097b596a6" oValue="EMEA">
            <span id="_IB_iconResourceWorkgroup">
                <img id="_IB_imgResourceWorkgroup" style="padding-right: 2px; margin-left: -1px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="_IBDD_InputKeyDown(document.getElementById('ResourceWorkgroup'), '1', event)" src="../../Images/UI/ddSelect1.gif" ctype="IB" icon1="../../Images/UI/ddSelect1.gif">
            </span>
            <br>
        <div id="_CPDDWRCC_div" style="width: 400px; height: 350px; margin-top: 0px; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 1010;" cpheight="350" cpwidth="400">
    <iframe id="_CPDDWRCC_ifr" src="../../UserControl/DropDownWkgResCusConTreeView/ifrDropDownWkgResCusConTreeView.aspx?rid=DA69AADD-D0A8-4551-A1E2-5FE83E99F914&amp;ResourceId=DA69AADD-D0A8-4551-A1E2-5FE83E99F914&amp;sno=0FA81AEE-A8AA-44B9-AE87-EF68727E874E&amp;SessionId=0FA81AEE-A8AA-44B9-AE87-EF68727E874E&amp;ui=W&amp;dialog=&amp;RDFilter=0&amp;model=3&amp;key=EMEA&amp;rfilter=&amp;cfilter=&amp;wgpfilter=-2032307166&amp;cusfilter=&amp;engfilter=&amp;prjfilter=&amp;taskfilter=&amp;oppfilter=&amp;campaignfilter=&amp;competitorfilter=&amp;invoicefilter=&amp;productfilter=&amp;requestfilter=&amp;surveyfilter=&amp;portfoliofilter=&amp;ignoreaccesscheck=False&amp;reportfilter=&amp;includesystem=false&amp;width=400&amp;height=350&amp;multiSelect=0&amp;multiselid=&amp;selectedbydblclick=0&amp;allrequests=false&amp;allresources=false&amp;additionalid=6c9ef9ce-daef-11d2-882b-006097b596a6&amp;requesttype=6c9ef9ce-daef-11d2-882b-006097b596a6&amp;entity=&amp;showclientportalparticipant=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-image: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>


            </div>
```

**EDIT:** here is the html when clicking on the drop down list:

```html
<div id="ddwccCPTreeBorder" style="width: 400px; height: 350px; -ms-overflow-x: scroll; -ms-overflow-y: scroll; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" onclick="_CPT_onCPTreeviewClick('ddwcc', event);" ondblclick="_CPT_onCPTreeviewDblClick('ddwcc', event);" ondragstart="_CPT_OnDragStart('ddwcc', event);">
    <div id="ddwccCPTree" topnode="1" blankpageurl="about:blank" dloadurl="about:blank"><div id="ddwcc6C9EF9CE_DAEF_11D2_882B_006097B596A6" style="white-space: nowrap;" cptype="gwgp" move="0" l="0" order="0"><img width="9" height="9" style="padding: 3px 1px 5px; cursor: default;" src="../../Images/Treeview/minus.gif" board="0" ct="pm"><img align="absmiddle" src="../../Images/Treeview/tvFolder.gif" border="0" hspace="3" ct="" eurl=""><span title="Services" style="cursor: pointer;"> Services</span></div><div id="sddwcc6C9EF9CE_DAEF_11D2_882B_006097B596A6" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 15px; display: block;" l="-1" epd="1"><div id="ddwcc5F0ED4A0_5FC5_4239_9876_5E9D9B468EC7" style="white-space: nowrap;" cptype="wgp" move="0" l="1" order="0"><img width="9" height="9" style="padding: 3px 1px 5px; cursor: default;" src="../../Images/Treeview/minus.gif" board="0" ct="pm"><img align="absmiddle" src="../../Images/Treeview/tvFolder.gif" border="0" hspace="3" ct="" eurl=""><span title="EMEA" style="cursor: pointer;">EMEA</span></div>
```

It is a long one, and I really appriciate if some one would be able to advise how to procceed. If more information is needed please let me know.

Regards,
Slava

Comment: I see an input text field, where do you see a dropdown in the html ?

Comment: I think it might be this: controltype="TWDropDown"  ? I mean from my attempts to make it work, the input text field is not enought to tirgger the change of the value in the system.

Comment: Would you be selecting APAC in the above?

Comment: No, the original value is APAC, the tagret value is "EMEA" (from column X(i))       Edit: I think once the macro runs, the EMEA value is being populated into oValue="EMEA">

Comment: is there HTML associated with the element you left click on to select?

Comment: Hi QHarr, I have edited the main post and added additional html code that shows the drop down. Here is an element that I can think off: <span title="EMEA" style="cursor: pointer;">EMEA</span>   As a user, I click on that span title and right after that click save. Clicking on that span title makes the changes be saved.

Comment: try ie.document.querySelector("[title=EMEA]").click

Comment: Hi Qharr, thank you for your reply. I have tried in varies ways, and it currently not working. I recieve error:  Run-time error '424': object required. Is there any other library besides html & IE controls that need to be selected in the references menu?

Comment: at the moment I have found 1000 ways how not to do it, but still no luck with finding the proper way to execute the code  so the value would be selected. Also, Is there a chance that span title can't be even clicked?

Comment: Any suggestions how if even possible to "leftclick" on div id, or any other approach?